# acceso a librerías css en estructura de proyecto error 404

Tags: html5

Tengo la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El directorio `example` es mi directorio `root`, para el proyecto;
en el archivo `test_web_full_1.php`

intento cargar el archivo de `BS` y me da error `404` y no tengo ni idea del por que, esta es la ruta que estoy usando:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../src/sources/bs5/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Alguien que me diga el error. no lo veo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya encontré el error...

esto solo se puede implementar en el `html` cuando la carpeta esta dentro de `root` y no por fuera... tuve que mover la carpeta a:

`"example/resources"`

esto sucede por que el "" resuelve del lado del cliente (frontend) ...
por lo tanto al intentar obtener el recurso no va a encontrar esa `url` ya que no forma parte del directorio del `root` del sitio.

en teoría solo funciona cuando el lenguaje que lo implementa resuelve del lado del servidor (backend) y exista la mecánica de cargar de esa manera los archivos como por ejemplo en `php`.